# Outlook 2003 Recently changed email flag status

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I mark emails I need to follow-up with the follow-up flag and look over my list of emails marked for follow up from the "Search Folders -> For Follow Up" folder.

I accidentally unflagged the wrong task (the one above the one I meant to click), and I have absolutely no idea what the task was.

Is there some way to see which emails have recently had their status changed?

If not, I'll probably have to look over all the mail in my inbox between the dates of the previous and next flagged emails, and hope to see something familiar... or let that mystery-task slip through the cracks..

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Use folders from now on.

Use "Follow Up" Flag only to mark next-action tasks.